# Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong in this Python Code and help me figure it out?

Tags: python, python-import, function

Here is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/endergreen/PyOS/SHOE/C.pyx", line 24, in <module>
        x.execute()
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Here is the set of code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import os as os
    import sys as sys
    import time as time
    import DefaultX as x

    def setup():
        execfile ("Setup.pyx")
        print ("Running...")
    def start():
        execfile ("/HDD/BOOT.pyrx")
        print ("Running...")
    def end():
        print ("Stopping...")
        time.sleep (3)

    x.machine_start
    x = raw_input (">>>")
    if x == 'setup':
        x.setup()
    if x == 'start':
        x.start()
    if x == 'execute':
        x.execute()
    if x == 'chkfile':
        x.chkfile()
    if x == 'chkinstall':
        x.chkdisk()
    if x == 'commands':
        x.cmds()
    else:
        print ("Unsupported Command")
        raw_input ("Press [Enter] to continue...")
        execfile ("C.pyx")
```

The error appears to be saying that the 'execute' function has not been defined in DefaultX.py, but I've used the SAME EXACT CODE (a literal copy-paste situation) in another project and it worked 100%! I have no clue what I'm doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what you expect to happend on `x.execute()` line? `x` is `str`

Comment: You are overridding x with  x = raw_input (">>>")

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code never worked, confident capital letters or not..

Comment: DSM, What code doesn't work? do you mean DefaultX? DefaultX is a custom module that I made.

Comment: @user3230819: I mean that the conflict in `x` didn't suddenly appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have conflicting definitions of `x`:

```
import DefaultX as x

x = raw_input (">>>")
```

Change one of them.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, for your answer. I'm bewildered as to how I made such a mistake.